# Class isn't added in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular function

```
$scope.show = function(el){

    if($scope.steps[el] == true){
        $scope.steps[el] = false;
    }
    else{
        $scope.steps = [];
        $scope.steps[el] = true;
    }
}
```

When I call It by click this

```
<span class="" ng-click="show('getDate')">text</span>
```

Then a class 'shown' adds in this div

```
<div class="form-block steps second" ng-class="{shown : steps.getDate}">
```

but I don't get the class when call the fanction in this cod

```
$(document).on('click', "li", function() {
    $scope.show('getDate');
    console.log($scope.steps);
});
```

but in console i get this log

```
[getDate: true]
```

LI tag generated with JS by jquery.formstyler http://dimox.name/jquery-form-styler/ from SELECT tag

Comment: Most of the time It's Is a poor behavior to use jQuery and not do it the `AngularJS` style. Is there a live site or a JSFiddle we can see ?

Comment: if you update scope using code outside of angular you have to tell angular to run digest cycle using `$apply()`. Just get rid of the jQuery and save yourself some headaches until you get to understand how angular works

Comment: @charlietfl, that was my tought too, but it show in `console` that it did passed via angular function and changed the values. Is `$apply` still needed ?

Comment: @OrelEraki right, the scope will get updated, but it won;t show in DOM

Comment: @Bhojendra Nepal, I need a class "shown", to apply my css animation, I don't use ng-show.

Comment: @Tony_m, you are in for a world of pain if you start modifying DOM outside of Angular, or if you are trying to "bolt on" Angular onto the existing app.

Comment: @New Dev, jquery on function is in my angular controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @charlietfl stated this is happening due the fact that you updated your DOM outside of the "Angular" world. Thus, resulting of angular not knowing you did such a change.

In order to fix it you should force angular to digest by using the keyword `$apply`.

Example:

```
$(document).on('click', "li", function() {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.show('getDate');
    });
    console.log($scope.steps);
});
```

**Important Note:** Most of the time It's poor behavior to use jQuery rather than  the AngularJS way.

- Thanks for @Bhojendra Nepal for noticing the bug.

Comment: How can I change to Angular way my jQuery consrtuction?